# Why is the correct answer deleted twice by moderators?

Tags: discussion, bounty, deleted-answers

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42219566/consume-sharepoint-office-365-web-services-from-java-application), but it did not get enough attention. I started a bounty, but even this way could not achieve enough attention. Some days later I found a nice tutorial which helped me to resolve my problem. I published it as an answer to help other users with the same problem and to mark my question as answered.

Quickly my answer was deleted by a moderator.

Later another user published the same link as an answer. I accepted it again as a correct answer and was about to award the bounty to him/her, but now I see that the correct answer is deleted again by a moderator.

What shall I do with the bounty?

Correct answers are deleted and the only answer that is there does not help to resolve the question.

Based on comments and the answer given, I understand the logic behind the decision of deleting of link-only answer.

I also prefer the have well expanded answer instead of a link. However, in this case the tutorial is big, and it would be too time-consuming resuming of the content without possible copyright infringement.
Thus the only alternatives would be: no answer or link-only answer.

And although I would prefer a link-only answer to no answer, I respect the Stack Overflow norms and will consider this question as non-answered.

Comment: Your answers consisted of nothing more than a link. Such posts are not considered valid answers, as they do not actually contain the solution. To someone looking for an answer, they are the moral equivalent of being told to ask somewhere else.

Comment: Link-only questions (that would become useless if the remote link goes down) are discouraged on Stack Overflow. What would help is if the answer at least summarized the contents (while of course acknowledging the article).

Comment: Link-only answers. Link dies, answer useless, not even any further clues. SO isn't a click-router. Answers here, or it is not an answer. Since I was beaten to the click, just to add the irony that otherwise an answer can contain any old rubbish, as long as you can twist in some way to say that it is an attempt to answer the question (or some question that may superficially be similar).

Comment: Also see [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really "good answers"?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231)

Comment: And, from the advice given, and your subsequent research, you can edit your answer to be a good one, and then try to get it undeleted.

Comment: Such posts get flagged, usually as VLQ.  Survival odds are very low.  You can put that kind of info in a comment, done.  It won't hurt to review the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), the section "Provide context for links" is most relevant.

Comment: Short answer: SO is a dictatorship.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I wasn't involved in deleting those answers, but I can see why there were deleted.

Stack Overflow discourages answers that don't have much substance of their own, and just link elsewhere. External links often go stale, and it's hard to guarantee that such an answer will remain useful in the future - which is what Stack Overflow essentially sets out to do.

A better way to handle such answers would be to extract the essential information from that tutorial, and possibly leave the link for extra details:

> To consume a Sharepoint 365 service from a Java application you should
>   1. First step...
>   2. Second step...
>   [etc..]
>
> For additional details, you could look at [this link]

Edit:
As noted in the comments, you shouldn't just copy-paste from the link, as that would infringe on the original author's copyright.

Comment: Also we need to inform the OP to not copy paste from the link, but write the answer in their own words and add the link for reference.

Comment: @BhargavRao good point. I though I conveyed this, but you're right, it's better to state this explicitly.

Comment: Another thing of note: you can't assign a bounty to a self-answer, so if the goal is to not let (half of) the bounty go to the answer with 4 upvotes, then a self-answer won't prevent that.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I do not want to assign a bounty to my answer. I want to assign bounty to another user who posted correct answer. Unfortunately I do not remember his username and I can not see his answer now

Comment: His name was Hitesh Shahani. You won't be able to contact him, though, he hasn't made any other contributions on Stack Overflow so far.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Thank you. It was complicated for me to find and separate this tutorial from the rest of the information, so for me it is a good contribution. But, as I explain in my edit, I understand better the situation about this question and leave it as it is

Comment: @Sergey: you can put a link to the tutorial in the comments.